# Attach OnCheckedChanged event to a div.onclick()

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, oncheckedchanged

Is it possible to fire the `OnCheckedChanged` event of an ASP.NET checkbox to a div?
So, when I click on the div, the `OnCheckedChanged` event should fire.

The checkboxes are inside a repeater and the checkbox and a label are surrounded by a div.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the div.onclick() handler fire the OnCheckedChanged event manually. Something like this:

```
div_onclick(object sender, eventargs e)
{
   checkbox_OnCheckedChanged(null, null); 
}
```